# How to convert RPM spec file dependencies to Python setup.py?

Tags: python, rpm, packaging, distutils, rpm-spec

Basically I'm working on porting a program from being packaged with RPM into using setup.py to package it as a wheel. My core question is whether there exists some guide or tool on how to make this conversion.

The key issue is that I'm looking to convert dependencies as specified by RPM's spec file to setup.py and can't find any information online as to how to do this.

Comment: Are you sure the RPM was not originally made with the help of an `setup.py`. Most python packages distributed as RPMs are (were?) using `python setup.py bdist_rpm`. That doesn't guarantee that there is a `setup.py` in the RPM you start of with, but you should at least unpack it an look for it.

Comment: Yeah I have access to the source, there is no setup.py file, it's legacy code that was packaged with RPM using a spec file.

Comment: Given the flexibility of what you can do with (pre-) install scripts in an RPM, I don't think you'll find a generic solution. Maybe you can post the content of the `.spec` (or a stripped down version) so the people here familiar with RPM and `setup.py` have a chance to come up with some "translation rules"

Answer (score 0):

Any answer likely depends on the distro for which the rpm was built.  A generic, albeit manual approach, would to start with `rpm -q --requires $PACKAGE` but as you already have the spec file, you can simply `rpmspec -q --requires *spec` to get that same info.  Look for the packages providing Python resources, e.g., `python3-requests`.  You'll need to translate each of these into the Python package name, e.g., `'requests'` for your setup.py.  You may find that `rpm -q --provides python3-requests` to be useful at this step; maybe not.